# Как создать уникальную страницу WP?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Есть сайт на WP с темой оформления. Хочу создать WP-страницу, лэндинг, которая вообще никак не будет связана с основным сайтом (то есть, никаких элементов, никаких стилей) Что мне для этого нужно? Создать land-page.php, туда загрузить html/css, далее этот шаблон будет виден в редакторе? И тогда создать страницу, унаследовав стиль из этого шаблона? Какие подводные камни следуют из этого способа?

Спасибо.

Comment: Проще залить статикой в корень сайта, но можно и через шаблон, да. Через шаблон может быть проблема, когда при подключении `get_header` вам надо будет разделять подключение css/js темы, которых вы не хотите видеть на вашем лендинге.

Comment: Ещё вариант создать файл с названием темы 

<?php
/*
* template name: landing
*/
?>
Далее HTML и CSS...


Теперь это обычный WP шаблон. Создать новую страницу и выбрать шаблон "landing". Из WP будет использоватся только URL.